# How to use custom elements in xaml for xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop xamarin forms app. I need to use UI elements that are customized. For example, instead of using Button, I need to use MyAppButton.

How can this feature be achieved? I think implementing a class MyAppButton by inheriting Button is a solution. Is this the right approach? Is there  any sample implementation available?

Thanks

Comment: see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to create custom control for radio button by referring https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML . I need to customise radio button icon. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, but you have to show what you have done and where you struggle and what your thoughts are. Please update the answer with this information. Tip: You have to look up how to change this icon on Android and iOS and modify the renderers.

Comment: I have used same code from posted link. So I thought not to duplicate code here

Answer (score 0):

> @user3165999 In Response to: 
>   'I need to customise radio button icon. Can anyone help me with this?'

First thing that you need to do is create Custom Renderer of an Element.
After that you need to write your custom style on *Renderer.cs modifying fields of Control (that is your element).

**For example in Android you can do something like:**

```
public class RadioButtonRenderer: ViewRenderer<CustomRadioButton, RadioButton>
{
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var radioButton = Control;
            // Resource.Drawable.backgroundradiobutton is an XML file that you have to create and insert in Resources -> Drawable -> backgroundradiobutton.xml
            Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.backgroundradiobutton, Resources.NewTheme());
            radioButton.SetButtonDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

> backgroundradiobutton.xml
>
> In this case this will have to be the file that contains the graphics of you radio button.
>   Note that radio button can use 'State List Drawables' class for change graphics based on state of RadioButton.
>   [More Info Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Most of the customization to graphics elements (eg buttons, sliders, etc) in Android are made via XML files.
If you do not know this environment, you should take a look.

Maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) can be helpful.

**On iOS you can do something like:**

```
class RadioButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomRadioButton, RadioButtonView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RadioButton> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var radioButton = Control;
        radioButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("pathofimageinreourcesfolder.png"), UIControlState.Application);
        // You need to set background image for each state.
    }
}
```

> As you can see iOS renderer accept images as graphics resource.
>
> In fact, (I think that) iOS customization is relatively simpler

I hope I was clear, sorry for my english.
Byee.